# Loop through Array of Objects within Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I hope you guys can help me.

First off, I know much has been said and written on this subject, and I *have* been reading up and trying various solutions for the last couple hours, but there is something I am missing.

I also believe it will possibly be a very simple task, so I apologize in advance for my ignorance.

**How do I loop though an Array of Objects within Objects in JavaScript?**

I have read one should use a **for...in** loop for arrays, but a simple **for** loop for objects, but exactly how to loop through and array of objects within object, eludes me.

**This is what I am trying to achieve:**

I want to display a list of reports (report name) in my UI that matches a specific ReportTemplateTypeId.

To do this, I am trying to loop through my retrieved data (after my data call), to build such a list to display.

The report names I want to display must have a ReportTemplateTypeId == 1

My Retrieved data looks like this: SelectableReportTemplateNames: [{{}},{{}},{{}},{{}}] with an Object within an Object within an Array.

Here is an actual example of the data, with 4 records I would like add to my list:

```
"SelectableReportTemplateNames": [
    {
        "ReportTemplateId": 1,
        "ReportTemplateName": "Proof of Receipt",
        "ReportTemplatePath": "...rdlc",
        "ReportTemplateType": {
            "ReportTemplateTypeId": 2,
            "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "Inventory - Proof of Receipt",
            "Id": null
        },
        "Id": "5653781274d4f23d4cbb54b8"
    },
    {
        "ReportTemplateId": 2,
        "ReportTemplateName": "Proof of Transfer",
        "ReportTemplatePath": ".....rdlc",
        "ReportTemplateType": {
            "ReportTemplateTypeId": 3,
            "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "Inventory - Proof of Transfer",
            "Id": null
        },
        "Id": "5653781274d4f23d4cbb54b9"
    },
    {
        "ReportTemplateId": 11,
        "ReportTemplateName": "All Calls Report",
        "ReportTemplatePath": "....rdlc",
        "ReportTemplateType": {
            "ReportTemplateTypeId": 1,
            "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "All Calls Report",
            "Id": null
        },
        "Id": "5739a89577801d7f0c10254c"
    },
    {
        "ReportTemplateId": 12,
        "ReportTemplateName": "High Priority Calls Report",
        "ReportTemplatePath": "......rdlc",
        "ReportTemplateType": {
            "ReportTemplateTypeId": 1,
            "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "High Priority Calls Report",
            "Id": null
        },
        "Id": "5739a89e77801d7f0c10254d"
    },
    {
        "ReportTemplateId": 13,
        "ReportTemplateName": "Call Asset Lines Report",
        "ReportTemplatePath": "......rdlc",
        "ReportTemplateType": {
            "ReportTemplateTypeId": 1,
            "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "Call Asset Lines Report",
            "Id": null
        },
        "Id": "5739aa7d77801d7f0c10254e"
    },
    {
        "ReportTemplateId": 16,
        "ReportTemplateName": "Daily Status Report",
        "ReportTemplatePath": ".....rdlc",
        "ReportTemplateType": {
            "ReportTemplateTypeId": 1,
            "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "Daily Status Report",
            "Id": null
        },
        "Id": "5739abb077801d7f0c102552"
    }
],
```

I thank you greatly in advance!

Comment: "I have read one should use a for...in loop for arrays, but a simple for loop for objects, but exactly how to loop through and array of objects within object, eludes me." No, it's the other way around.

Comment: So for clarity you want to loop through this list and print all report names that has ID === 1. Am I right?

Comment: As a side note: I am using MongoDB as he DB and AngularJS for my view and controllers. I have tried various Angular filters to display only the filtered data, but get errors. I have tried things like: ng-options="reportSettingsData.SelectableReportTemplateNames | filter:reportType('1') and ng-options="report as reportSettingsData.SelectableReportTemplateNames for report in SelectableReportTemplateNames | filter:ReportTemplateTypeId: 1" and others.

Comment: have you tried lodash, it will easy and it will work.

_.find(SelectableReportTemplateNames,function(eachReportTemplate){

return eachReportTemplate.ReportTemplateType.ReportTemplateTypeId ==1;
})

Comment: @Rajesh That is correct

Comment: @SundarBons In which setting would I use _.find? In MongoDB or in JavaScript? to be honest I have not seen that being used in JavaScript (not in my limited experience)

Comment: @onmyway in JS, find for one result filter for more than one result.

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#find - refer this link for docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through it with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var object = { "SelectableReportTemplateNames": [{ "ReportTemplateId": 1, "ReportTemplateName": "Proof of Receipt", "ReportTemplatePath": "...rdlc", "ReportTemplateType": { "ReportTemplateTypeId": 2, "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "Inventory - Proof of Receipt", "Id": null }, "Id": "5653781274d4f23d4cbb54b8" }, { "ReportTemplateId": 2, "ReportTemplateName": "Proof of Transfer", "ReportTemplatePath": ".....rdlc", "ReportTemplateType": { "ReportTemplateTypeId": 3, "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "Inventory - Proof of Transfer", "Id": null }, "Id": "5653781274d4f23d4cbb54b9" }, { "ReportTemplateId": 11, "ReportTemplateName": "All Calls Report", "ReportTemplatePath": "....rdlc", "ReportTemplateType": { "ReportTemplateTypeId": 1, "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "All Calls Report", "Id": null }, "Id": "5739a89577801d7f0c10254c" }, { "ReportTemplateId": 12, "ReportTemplateName": "High Priority Calls Report", "ReportTemplatePath": "......rdlc", "ReportTemplateType": { "ReportTemplateTypeId": 1, "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "High Priority Calls Report", "Id": null }, "Id": "5739a89e77801d7f0c10254d" }, { "ReportTemplateId": 13, "ReportTemplateName": "Call Asset Lines Report", "ReportTemplatePath": "......rdlc", "ReportTemplateType": { "ReportTemplateTypeId": 1, "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "Call Asset Lines Report", "Id": null }, "Id": "5739aa7d77801d7f0c10254e" }, { "ReportTemplateId": 16, "ReportTemplateName": "Daily Status Report", "ReportTemplatePath": ".....rdlc", "ReportTemplateType": { "ReportTemplateTypeId": 1, "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "Daily Status Report", "Id": null }, "Id": "5739abb077801d7f0c102552" }] };

object.SelectableReportTemplateNames.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.ReportTemplateType.ReportTemplateTypeId === 1) {
        document.write(a.ReportTemplateName + '<br>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to add the item of the match to an array. But it adds empty [objects]. Any idea? See:
 
`function getReportNames() {

            var allReportNames = vm.reportSettingsData; // myArray
            var selectedReportNames = [];
           allReportNames.SelectableReportTemplateNames.forEach(function (a) {
                if (a.ReportTemplateType.ReportTemplateTypeId === 1) {
                    selectedReportNames += a;
                }
            });
            vm.selectedReportNames = selectedReportNames;
            return vm.selectedReportNames
        }`

Comment: you need to push `selectedReportNames.push(a)` instead of adding.

Answer (score 2):

If its just about printing necessary value, you can directly put logic on view.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/qg1ftbsc/1/)

#### View Binding

```html
<select 
  ng-model="test"
  ng-options="item.ReportTemplateId as item.ReportTemplateName for item in data.SelectableReportTemplateNames | filter:isValid">
</select>
```

#### Filter function

```js
$scope.isValid = function(o) {
  return o.ReportTemplateType.ReportTemplateTypeId == 1;
}
```

#### Demo

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    "SelectableReportTemplateNames": [{
      "ReportTemplateId": 1,
      "ReportTemplateName": "Proof of Receipt",
      "ReportTemplatePath": "...rdlc",
      "ReportTemplateType": {
        "ReportTemplateTypeId": 2,
        "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "Inventory - Proof of Receipt",
        "Id": null
      },
      "Id": "5653781274d4f23d4cbb54b8"
    }, {
      "ReportTemplateId": 2,
      "ReportTemplateName": "Proof of Transfer",
      "ReportTemplatePath": ".....rdlc",
      "ReportTemplateType": {
        "ReportTemplateTypeId": 3,
        "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "Inventory - Proof of Transfer",
        "Id": null
      },
      "Id": "5653781274d4f23d4cbb54b9"
    }, {
      "ReportTemplateId": 11,
      "ReportTemplateName": "All Calls Report",
      "ReportTemplatePath": "....rdlc",
      "ReportTemplateType": {
        "ReportTemplateTypeId": 1,
        "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "All Calls Report",
        "Id": null
      },
      "Id": "5739a89577801d7f0c10254c"
    }, {
      "ReportTemplateId": 12,
      "ReportTemplateName": "High Priority Calls Report",
      "ReportTemplatePath": "......rdlc",
      "ReportTemplateType": {
        "ReportTemplateTypeId": 1,
        "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "High Priority Calls Report",
        "Id": null
      },
      "Id": "5739a89e77801d7f0c10254d"
    }, {
      "ReportTemplateId": 13,
      "ReportTemplateName": "Call Asset Lines Report",
      "ReportTemplatePath": "......rdlc",
      "ReportTemplateType": {
        "ReportTemplateTypeId": 1,
        "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "Call Asset Lines Report",
        "Id": null
      },
      "Id": "5739aa7d77801d7f0c10254e"
    }, {
      "ReportTemplateId": 16,
      "ReportTemplateName": "Daily Status Report",
      "ReportTemplatePath": ".....rdlc",
      "ReportTemplateType": {
        "ReportTemplateTypeId": 1,
        "ReportTemplateTypeDescription": "Daily Status Report",
        "Id": null
      },
      "Id": "5739abb077801d7f0c102552"
    }]
  }
  
  $scope.isValid = function(o){
   return o.ReportTemplateType.ReportTemplateTypeId == 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select 
      ng-model="test"
      ng-options="item.ReportTemplateId as item.ReportTemplateName for item in data.SelectableReportTemplateNames | filter:isValid">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** This answer assumes `ReportTemplateType` will always be an object and not an array.

Comment: I love the simplicity of what you are showing. i am using drop down fields for this, using ng-model and ng-options. This does not make use of ng-repeat; how can I implement it however?

Comment: Thanks for the help - I am getting the following error: "Error: [IOWA Error] [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'as' is an unexpected token at column 23 of the expression [item.ReportTemplateId as item.ReportTemplateName for item in data.SelectableReportTemplateNames | filter:isValid] starting at [as item.ReportTemplateName for item in data.SelectableReportTemplateNames | filter:isValid].

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1: Get the array

`var dataArray = data["SelectableReportTemplateNames"];`,

*assuming your root object is called `data`.*

### Step 2: Loop through the array

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) { 
    //do stuff here
}
```

### Step 3: Print data when your predicate holds

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) { 
    if(dataArray[i]["ReportTemplateType"]["ReportTemplateTypeId"] == 1) {
        console.log(dataArray[i]["ReportTemplateName"]);
    }
}
```

Just to let you know, objects and arrays behave like eachother when it comes to indexing (e.g. `data["key"]`) and accessing (e.g. `data.key`)

Comment: Thank you for he feedback. I am however trying to get the data based upon the ReportTemplateTypeId (not ReportTemplateId) nested inside the object you are looping through {ReportTemplateType}. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh ok my bad, see my updated answer. It's pretty straightforward tbh

Comment: Thanks. I see how it works:) I am trying to add the matching records to an array to display, but only add an empty [Object]. So instead of console.log, how would you add the data to an array? I have tried myArray += dataArray[i] and returning.

Comment: adding anything to a list in javascript is done by the `.push()` function. E.g. `var list = [1,3,7]; list.push(5); console.log(list); //prints [1,3,7,5]`Of course if you care about the key of the value you can explicitly say `list[key] = value`

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is like that and is not going to change in a long time, you can hardcode your loops:

```
var outerArray = whateverNameYourVariableHas["SelectableReportTemplateNames"];
for (var objIndex = 0; objIndex < outerArray.length; objIndex++) {
    var currentObject = outerArray[objIndex];
    // handle your objects here

   var templateType - currentObject["ReportTemplateType"];

   for (var templateTypeProperty in templateType) {
       // handle template type properties here.
       // in this loop, templateTyeProperty is a string with the name of the current property.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//try this;

$.each(data,SelectableReportTemplateNames,function(a,b){

console.log(b.ReportTemplateId);
console.log(b.ReportTemplateName);

});

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Mozilla Developer Network - Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [Mozilla Developer Network - Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Everything you need for filtering, sorting and general data manipulation can be found there.

**EXAMPLES**

Assuming that the data is loaded into a handle named `data`, then the following snippet will give you an array of elements matching your condition:

```
data.SelectableReportTemplateNames.filter(function (el) {
    return (el.ReportTemplateId === 1);
});
/*OUTPUTS
[{
        "ReportTemplateId" : 1,
        "ReportTemplateName" : "Proof of Receipt",
        "ReportTemplatePath" : "...rdlc",
        "ReportTemplateType" : {
            "ReportTemplateTypeId" : 2,
            "ReportTemplateTypeDescription" : "Inventory - Proof of Receipt",
            "Id" : null
        },
        "Id" : "5653781274d4f23d4cbb54b8"
    }
]
*/
```

From here you could call `forEach` to loop through the elements and get output their results:

```
data.SelectableReportTemplateNames.filter(function (el) {
    return (el.ReportTemplateId === 1);
}).forEach(function (el) {
    console.log(el.ReportTemplateName);
    alert(el.ReportTemplateName);
});
/* ALERTS AND CONSOLE LOGS: "Proof of Receipt" */
```

**EDIT 1**

I somehow misread the question, so below is a fixed expression that filters by `ReporttemplateTypeId` instead of `ReportTemplateId`:

```
data.SelectableReportTemplateNames.filter(function (el) {
    return (el.ReportTemplateType.ReportTemplateTypeId === 1);
}).forEach(function (el) {
    console.log(el.ReportTemplateName);
    alert(el.ReportTemplateName);
});
/* OUTPUTS
All Calls Report
High Priority Calls Report
Call Asset Lines Report
Daily Status Report
/*
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would like to filter one object deeper. Not ReportTemplateId, but ReporttemplateTypeId === 1. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = youArrayName["SelectableReportTemplateNames"];

$scope.filteredArray = myArray.filter(function(x){
  return x.ReportTemplateId === 1;
 })
//Filter will be an array containing all that have ReportTemplateId as 1

//Use in ng-repeat like
<p ng-repeat="x in filteredArray">{{x.ReportTemplateName}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

By MongoDb

```
db.YourCollection.find({ "SelectableReportTemplateNames.ReportTemplateType.ReportTemplateTypeId" : 1});
```

By JS

```
var resultTemplate = _.find(SelectableReportTemplateNames,function(eachTemplate){
  return eachTemplate.ReportTemplateType.ReportTemplateTypeId == 1;
})
```